# Why this sentence contains an "in"?

Tags: attributives

> Zhou unveiled details of the space station during a ceremony in which the reentry capsule of China's manned spacecraft Shenzhou X was given to the Hunan provincial government.

This is an attributive clause. I can't understand why "which" should add an "in" before? How to rephrase the sentence? Where to put "in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, **which** is a relative pronoun which links the main clause "Zhou unveiled..." with the defining relative clause "the re-entry capsule... was given...".

**which** refers to **ceremony** in the main clause, and the relative clause explains what happened **in** the particular ceremony mentioned in the main clause, hence **in which**.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as two sentences.

> Zhou unveiled details of the space station during a ceremony. In the ceremony, the reentry capsule of China's manned spacecraft Shenzhou X was given to the Hunan provincial government.